# RecyclerView with items that hide/show their childs

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` in which items are a `LinearLayout` with several `TextViews` as childs. Depending on some rules (this is decided in `onBindViewHolder`), the `TextViews` might be hidden away (visibility GONE) or shown.

My problem is that if I have for example 3 items (A, B and C) in the `RecyclerView` with the same number of visible `TextViews` and A is on top of the list, B in the middle and C at the bottom, if for example B has to show more `TextViews` than before, during a brief period of time this item (B) will overlap with C since it has grown in size and has to accommodate the new visible `TextViews` which were previously with visibility GONE.

Visual representation of the problem:

**Desired situation**

[image]

**Current and undesired situation**

[image]

After a bit the `RecyclerView`accommodates the item correctly.

How can I avoid this from happening?

EDIT:

In one of the comments is suggested that I might have to animate and transforms the views myself. Is that necessary or is there another way of doing it? If so, how can I animate and transform the views?

EDIT 2:

Tried this answer: [Animating items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724964/how-to-animate-recyclerview-items-when-they-appear), but the problems persists. There's a visible delay until the `RecyclerView` updates.

EDIT 3:

I am using this class ([RecyclerViewCursorAdapter](https://gist.github.com/quanturium/46541c81aae2a916e31d)) as base for the adapter that populates the `RecyclerView`. Aditionally, I am doing this in `onResume`

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if(getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(R.id.myLoaderId) == null)
    {
        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(R.id.myLoaderId, null, this);
    }
    else
    {
        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(R.id.myLoaderId, null, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try making the `TextViews` `INVISIBLE` instead of `GONE`.

Comment: Can you post your code showing what's going on? If the data changes you should be able to simply call recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); and it should redraw the recyclerView correctly.

Comment: @LNI I am doing that, but as stated, the problem arises during a brief period of time (I guess while the `RecyclerView` updates), then it is rendered correctly.

Comment: @sonictt1 That would leave 'holes' in the item, and since some items will have some `TextViews` active and others don't it will have an undesired appearance for me.

Comment: You question is unclear. Perhaps you could post an image for better illustration of what you're trying to describe.

Comment: If you can't reserve space in the item for the text that might appear, you'll have to transform and animate your views by hand as RecyclerView only redraws your view after it has exited and re-entered the screen.

Comment: @sonictt1 Ok, could be. But why is it that it worked with `ListView` but not with `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @Elye Updated post with pictures.

Answer (score 1):

The key was using the **setIsRecyclable()** method of **RecyclerView.ViewHolder class**. Set this property true as [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702357/android-recyclerview-content-messed-up-after-scrolling#comment86302639_38594061)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that: in your xml (item view), you declare textView with default attribute:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

when check condition:

```
if (condition) {
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Instead of that, you should do like this:

```
if (condition) {
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: I am doing what you suggest. The problem is that when the visibility is changed to `VISIBLE`, the `RecyclerView` shows for a brief period of time the item with new height but overlapping the item below.

Comment: My code is exactly as yours if you remove the data binding and all that stuff

Answer (score 0):

if its height becomes 0, it won't be visible :). I assume your root layout does have some min height (or exact height) that makes it still take space even though it is GONE.

Answer (score 0):

If you also need to add smooth animation effect,try this one.

By default put visibility == gone.

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position);

    holderG.layoutReply.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

And set visibility something like :

```
 holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                        if (holderG.layoutReply.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {                   
                            notifyItemChanged(holderG.getAdapterPosition());
                        }
                        else {holderG.layoutReply.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

and in your inflator layout set

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

for parent layout.

Note-- in case of visibility==VISIBLE, animate layout changes works fine and smooth but in case of visibility==GONE items overlap each other thats why I am using notifyItemChanged to change back the visibility of view.

Answer (score 0):

Use `notifyItemChanged(int position)` function provided by the RecyclerView adpater to notify that an item got changed.