# Change RecyclerView item margins dynamically

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am working on a freelance android project. I have a problem with changing margins between RecyclerView items as project design need. I want to show half of last visible item in screen so user can guess to scroll horizontally. I tried it with creating a custom RecyclerView.ItemDecoration. When screen first opened everything was okay but when I start to scroll horizontally on this RecyclerView, margin between items increased and sometimes decreased. How can I solve this problem with a general way. With image below you can see the my desired look. It is the first time when screen opened.
Thanks everyone.

[image]

Comment: Why does nobody help me? Is not that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have required reputation to comment on the post.

Put your layout code for recycler view items and ur adapter. Try resetting and setting the item's margin.

Check this [RecyclerView Item Alignment Going Wrong]:[Android: RecyclerView content messed up after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702357/android-recyclerview-content-messed-up-after-scrolling)